# Combinatorial game in java

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, combinatorics

I've got an assignment for a computer science class. I've been thinking about the answer for more than two weeks now without success so I decided to give it a try in here.
The game consists of 4 CIA agents using 4 adjacent telephone booths. They arrive at the set of booths one at a time, following certain rules:

1 - An agent chooses a booth that has its two neighbouring booths unoccupied (this includes the booths at the edges of the set);
2 - If the condition above isn't met, the agent chooses a booth that has only one neighbouring booth unoccupied; and
3 - If both conditions fail, the agent chooses any booth.

There are eight different ways of occupying the booths given 4 agents and 4 booths, according to the rules. An example: agent #1 occupies the first booth (the left edge one), then agent #2 occupies the third booth (from left to right), then agent #3 occupies the fourth booth and finally agent #4 occupies the second booth.

We are asked to write a code that counts the number of ways that 19 agents occupy 19 booths, according to these rules.

My natural choice for this problem was creating an array of boolean, in which false represents a vacant booth and true represents an occupied booth:

```html
public class AgentGame {

    private boolean[] booths;
    private int numberOfBooths, counter;

    public AgentGame(int nb) {

        counter = 0;
        numberOfBooths = nb;
        booths = new boolean[numberOfBooths];

    }
```

I've been trying to think of a way of implementing two methods, one for filling the booths according to the rules and another one for counting all the different combinations in which the booths can be occupied. But I wasn't able to figure it out, not yet. Any ideas here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to go with recursive method. If you don't figure it out, I'll post some code in an hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat inefficient, but I hope clear solution. I can't guarantee that this will output right answer (as I love to make stupid mistakes), but this should give you an idea how to solve it.

```
package whyNotZoidberg;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Agents {

    public static final int N = 5;  // amount of total agents / booths 

    static int position[] = new int[N]; // index = agent, value = boot
    static boolean occupied[] = new boolean[N];
    static ArrayList<Integer> answers = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            position[i] = -1;
        }

        System.out.println("Solutions: ");
        int answer = getWays(0);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The answer is ");
        System.out.println(answer);
        System.out.println();
        Collections.sort(answers,new Comparator<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                if (o1 > o2) {
                    return 1;
                }
                if (o2 > o1) {
                    return -1;
                }
                System.out.println("Repetition between answers detected. Quiting.");
                System.exit(0);
                return 0;
            }
        });
        System.out.println("The solutions are following (the number is agent number)");
        for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(answers.get(i));
        }
    }

    static int getWays(int agentNr) {
        if (agentNr == N-1) {

            position[N-1] = viableBootOptions().get(0);

            int number = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                    if (position[j] == i) {
                        number += (int) ((j+1) * Math.pow(10, N - i - 1));
                    }
                }
            }

            answers.add(number);

            return 1;     

        }

        int result = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> options = viableBootOptions();

        for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++) {
            position[agentNr] = options.get(i);
            for (int j = agentNr + 1; j < N; j++) {
                position[j] = -1;
            }
            updateOccupied();
            result += getWays (agentNr + 1);
        }

        return result;

    }

    static ArrayList<Integer> viableBootOptions() {
        int ruleSelected = 3;
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

        if (!occupied[0] && !occupied[1]) {
            ruleSelected = 1;
            result.add(0);
        }
        if (!occupied[N-2] && !occupied[N-1]) {
            ruleSelected = 1;
            result.add(N-1);
        }
        if (!occupied[0]) {
            if (ruleSelected != 1) {
                ruleSelected = 2;
                result.add(0);
            }
        }
        if (!occupied[N-1]) {
            if (ruleSelected != 1) {
                ruleSelected = 2;
                result.add(N-1);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < N-1; i++) {
            if (!occupied[i]) {
                if (!occupied[i - 1] && !occupied[i + 1]) {
                    if (ruleSelected > 1) {
                        ruleSelected = 1;
                        result.clear();
                    }
                    result.add(i);
                    continue;
                }
                if ((!occupied[i - 1] || !occupied[i + 1]) && ruleSelected != 1) {

                    if (ruleSelected > 1) {
                        if (ruleSelected == 3) {
                            result.clear();
                        }
                        ruleSelected = 2;   
                        result.add(i);
                        continue;
                    }

                }

                if (ruleSelected == 3) {
                    result.add(i);
                }

            }
        }
        return result;

    }

    static void updateOccupied() {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            occupied[i] = false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (position[i] > -1) {
                occupied[position[i]] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Program now also prints all answers found, as well as terminates if any of the answers repeats. You can change amount of agents by changing value of N.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your code has returned the correct value of 8 combinations in the case of 4 agents and 4 booths.

Comment: Would there be any impact in the code if I changed rule number one to 1 - An agent chooses a booth that has its two neighbouring booths unoccupied (this includes the booths at the edges of the set, **if that's the case**);?

Comment: Here's the example of occupation for 4 agents and 4 booths: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0TQx17rlFBIVEROSnd6TXhaZGM/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: What you mean change? I think rule number one already is that what you just described. Also what you mean by ward impact? If you mean the speed of execution, then I doubt if there is really any way to speed up execution of exactly this approach. I estimate that time required to calculate will be around 19! / 36000000000 = ~3000000 hours.

Comment: I asked that because I manually calculated the number of combinations for a set of 5 agents and 5 booths, giving a result of 24 combinations, but the code returned 32. Though, I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. How would you proceed to test the code for sets of 4, 5, ... , 19 booths? I'm proceeding as follows: for example, for a set of 4 booths and 4 agents, whenever I found a 19, I replaced it with a 4; whenever I found an 18, I replaced it with a 3 and whenever I found a 17, I replaced it with a 2. And so on for the other sets. Does that make any sence to you?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by ward impact.

Comment: not ward but word. Typo. I'll update my answer so you can easily change amount of agents

Comment: @Lucas Edited my answer so now you can quickly change quantity of agents by changing value of N. Also I went through when N = 5, and I'm pretty sure, that answer is 32 (run it yourself and see if you can see any invalid answer).

Comment: I ran the code for a value of N = 11; I obtained an answer but also got the message "Repetition between answers detected. Quiting." What is the purpose of that message? Does it mean that the answer cannot be obtained?

Comment: Or maybe it means that the possibilities cannot be printed?

Comment: It means that the answer (11 digit number) is bigger than maximum integer value. Replace Integer with Long and you should be fine.

Comment: Given that line counting begins in the first import, I've replaced Integer with Long in lines 11, 31, 34 and 57 and still got the message "Repetition between answers detected. Quiting."; am I doing this correctly? Where exactly should I replace Integer with Long?

Comment: I've tried to move this discussion to chat but I need more reputation. A few strange things happened while testing the last version of the code. I think it's natural that answers with more than 10 digits cannot be printed out because we don't have a one-character representation for a value greater than 10 (the available representations are 0 to 9). For an N equals 14 I got an ugly _java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded_ I will continue studying the code because I think it's a good approach.

Comment: No, it is not good enough approach for numbers >14 as it is too slow. If you really want to calculate answer for 19 agents, you have to write something way more faster. As I initially and said this is inefficient but clear solution. So if you feel you understand how this code works, you should move on and find a more efficient solution. I feel like this requires more maths than programming, so maybe try to solve it on paper.

Comment: I got the confirmation your code is correct for N = 1 to 14.

Answer (score 0):

I will make this quick uni code ( works for any code if u know what to do)

```
              Int x,z=1
              Int numberofagents;
              Int numberofbooths;
              Int emptynext; //this value allows you to control how many empty booths need to be next to one in order for an agent to pic 
              Func sortagents (numberofagents,numberofbooths,emptynext) {              



      If(booth[emptybooth].numbertotherightt>=emptyadj||booth[emptybooth].numbertotheleft>=emptyadj,z+1)
       Return (agent[z].boothnumber=emptybooth);//this statement will put agents in booths with 2 empty adjacent ones first          If(booth[emptybooth].numbertotheright>=1||booth[emptybooth].numbertotheleft>=1,z+1)
             Return (agent[z].boothnumber=emptybooth);//that one will place them into booths with one empty adjacent};   
              Int randomnumber=numberofbooths/2 //I forgot   the function for rounding but round up
              Int Boothstaken;
              Int Boothstaken=0;
              Class Booth[numberofbooths]{
              Bool Occupied;
              Int  Unoccupiedonright;
             Int  Unoccupiedonleft;
             }
             Class Agent[numberofagents]{
             Int boothnumber;
             }
             Func Boothsoccupied (x=1)
             If (booth[x].y=true&&x<Numberofbooths,x+1)
             {int Boothstaken+1
             };
             Func BoothPick //Agent picks booth
             If(Boothstaken=0,z+1)
             {agent[z].boothnumber=randomnumber}
             If(Boothstaken>0)
             {Func sortagents};
```

I really hope this helps This will simply give you where each person goes so to find where someone goes it's simply 
Agent[number you want].Boothnumber
Changing that to Java and outputting it is your job
I'll be back in a minute and give you the function to find out how many booths are to the left or right that are empty need to eat so I'll be back in a minute

```
            Hopes this helps :) Good Luck :)
```

Comment: I will add comments to it :) I'm actually quiet intrigued with this question thank you